# Application of GRR in number theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

In Neukirch's book *Algebraic Number Theory*, page 254, the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch Theorem is stated, but no applications are given.

Do you know references for applications for this theorem, or maybe explain some applications, in the special case of number fields, following the philosophy of Neukirch?

Thank you all.

Comment: @Integrand I'm thinking about sponsoring a bounty on this. Do you think it would work?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Before you do, just so you know this is not the literal geometric GRR, this is more like a reinterpretation of GRR in the vein of Arakaelov geometry. The OP's question is answered probably in most beginning texts on the subject.

Comment: Thanks @AlexYoucis. While I might learn something from an answer, it may be better to invest on something else. If you see a question where a bounty may help (or one that has an exceptional answer), drop me a note in [the Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive). You are one of the people whose judgement I trust.